# Mongodb queries (aggregation framework) take enormously slow time

Tags: mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework, nosql

I'm having a not really large dataset (>100000 records).
But the aggregate queries that I run on them are taking really long time.

I there's an index on `_type` field. And when I run

```javascript
db.getCollection('product').find({_type:"healthcare"}).count()
```

I get response in 0.015 sec...

But when I run for example

```javascript
db.getCollection('product').aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$_type",sum:{$sum:1}}}])
```

I am waiting for 40 seconds to get a response.

What can possibly be wrong with index-only aggregate query like that? Where should I look to find a problem?

MongoDB version is 3.0+. wiredTiger data storage. And here are the `db.stats()` output:

```javascript
{
    "collections" : 3,
    "objects" : 113090,
    "avgObjSize" : 259186.2551949774497189,
    "dataSize" : 29311373600.0000000000000000,
    "storageSize" : 29317480288.0000000000000000,
    "numExtents" : 36,
    "indexes" : 4,
    "indexSize" : 15379056.0000000000000000,
    "fileSize" : 32130465792.0000000000000000,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "extentFreeList" : {
        "num" : 2,
        "totalSize" : 9.85907e+06
    },
    "dataFileVersion" : {
        "major" : 4,
        "minor" : 22
    },
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation on [pipeline operators and indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes), the `$group` pipeline operator cannot use an index:

> The `$match` and `$sort` pipeline operators can take advantage of an index
>   when they occur at the beginning of the pipeline.
>
> *New in version 2.4:* The `$geoNear` pipeline operator takes advantage of a geospatial index. When using `$geoNear`, the `$geoNear` pipeline
>   operation must appear as the first stage in an aggregation pipeline.
>
> Even when the pipeline uses an index, aggregation still requires
>   access to the actual documents; i.e. indexes cannot fully cover an
>   aggregation pipeline.
>
> *Changed in version 2.6:* In previous versions, for very select use cases, an index could cover a pipeline.

So your `$group` aggregate is slow because it will use a full collection scan.

However, it's worth noting that the `aggregate` equivalent of your `find` query that you're comparing against would be:

```js
db.getCollection('product').aggregate([
    {$match: {_type: 'healthcare'}},
    {$group: {_id: null, sum: {$sum: 1}}}
])
```

and because that query starts with a `$match` operator, it would use an index and the performance should be more comparable.